# "Does someone have or knows where to find" wrong grammar?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I think it should be "Does someone have or know where to find". But the "knows" doesn't immediately intuitively raise a red flag for me.

E.g. "Does someone got solutions or knows where to find them"

Comment: _Does someone knows_ and _does someone got_ are wrong as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: *Does someone knows* is always wrong.  *Do* is the main verb, so that is the one that you conjugate.  *Know* stays as the bare infinitive and is not conjugated.

Comment: @stangdon You should post that as an answer. It is an important point.

Answer (score 1):

When forming questions with "do" in English, this verb is considered to be the main verb, and is conjugated as "does" when used with the third person singular "someone".

The verbs which follow do/does must be in the bare infinitive form. There are no exceptions, so this is an easy rule to remember.

> Do I know you?
>
> Do you know me?
>
> Does he know me?
>
> Does someone know him?
>
> Do we know them?
>
> Do you have an apple?
>
> Does someone have an apple?
>
> Do we have any apples?

If you want to ask a do question in the past tense you must use the past tense form **did** - but the verbs which follow must be the bare infinite form (not the past tense form). So in your second example "got" is incorrect.

> Did someone get it?
>
> Did someone know him?
>
> Did he see her?

Answer (score 0):

There is a parallel structure in the verbs.  The two verbs "have" and "know" have the same subject, and they should have the same form

In this case both are in their base form.  The structure of the question is "Does someone {bare infinitive}" so it must be "Does someone have or know where to find...."

You might like to punctuate this with the "or..." phrase as a parenthesis:

> Does someone have, or know where to find, a solution to this problem?

Similarly "Does someone got solutions" is incorrect.  The auxiliary verb is conjugated:  "Did someone get solutions, or know where to find them?"

Answer (score 0):

“Does someone have or know” is the correct way to phrase this question.
“Knows” is the singular, present-tense form of the verb and is used with “he”, “she”, “it”, or a name.

Answer (score -1):

I'd normally use "Does anyone have or ..." rather than "someone"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).